# Java Guessing Game stats extension

Tags: java

I'm making a guessing game program for school. So far, here's my code:

```
package chapter5;
import java.util.*;
public class ProgrammingProject3 {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int tries = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess = 0;
    boolean win = false;
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");
    while (win == false){
        guess = scanner.nextInt();
        tries++;
        if (guess > 100 || guess < 1){
            System.out.println("Your number must be between 1 and 100!");
        }else if(guess == num){
            win = true;
        } else if(guess < num){
            System.out.println("Higher! Guess again.");
        } else if(guess > num){
            System.out.println("Lower! Guess again.");
        }
    }
    if (win == true){
        if (tries <= 5){
            System.out.println("Amazing! You got it in " + tries + " guesses! The number was " + num + ".");
        } else if (tries <= 10){
            System.out.println("Pretty good, you guessed the number in " + tries + " guesses. The number was " + num + ".");
        } else if (tries <= 15){
            System.out.println("Try harder next time. You guessed the number in " + tries + " guesses. The number was " + num + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ouch! you guessed the number in " + tries + " guesses. The number was " + num + ".");
    }
    }
}
```

}

It works fine for me, but I also need to extend the program to make it accept playing multiple programs until the user chooses to stop (with a sentinel), and then give stats about total and average number of guesses. Thanks for your help

Comment: Consider circling the entire thing in a `do while`. Keep track of your total runs with a counter, and save each `tries` to an `ArrayList` or something and then average the values in it.

Comment: Another loop enclosing the entire thing that checks for input to indicate whether the user wants to continue or quit?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement another while-loop around your two while-loops and ask the user each time if he wants to play again. Based on this choice you enter the loop again or go to the end. For your statistic you need another integer to count the number of the games.